# Solving weighted least squares with non-negative constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, linear-programming, least-squares, quadratic-programming

I have the optimization problem

$$
\begin{align}
\min_{\mathbf{P} \geq 0} \|\mathbf{A\odot(X-PQ^\top)}\|^2 + \frac{\|\mathbf{P}\|^2}{2}
\end{align}
$$
$\odot$ is the Hadamard product, $\mathbf{A,X,P,Q}$ are matrices and $\|\cdot\|^2$ is the Frobenius norm.

I am trying to solve this problem. My approach is based on Lagrangian and taking the gradient.

Gradient of the Lagrangian gives me,
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A\odot(X-PQ^\top)} + \mathbf{P} = \Lambda,\, \Lambda \text{ is the dual variable} 
\end{align}

Now using the fact that Λ≥0, can I frame the above problem as an LP as given below

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
&minimize ~~~0 \\
\text{ such that} \quad
&\mathbf{A\odot(X-PQ^\top)} + \mathbf{P} \geq 0
\end{split}
\end{align}

Is this LP formulation correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following set of definitions
$$\eqalign{
\def\l{\lambda}
\def\L{\left} \def\R{\right}
\def\b{\big}  \def\B{\Big}
&\l^2 = \tfrac12 \\
&a = {\rm vec}(A),\quad \;\;p = {\rm vec}(P),\quad x = {\rm vec}(X)\\
&D={\rm Diag}(a),\quad b=Dx,\qquad\; H=D(Q\otimes I) \\
&F = A\odot(PQ^T-X) \\
&f = {\rm vec}(F) = Hp-b \\
}$$
Vectorization does not change the value of the Frobenius norm, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
\b\|A\b\|_F^2 \;=\; \b\|a\b\|_F^2 \\
}$$
The objective function can be reformulated as
$$\eqalign{
\def\H{\widehat H} \def\q{\overline b_\  }
\phi(p)
 &= \b\|F\b\|_F^2 \qquad\;\;+\; \,\tfrac12\,\b\|P\b\|_F^2 \\
 &= \b\|Hp-b\b\|_F^2 \;+\; \l^2\b\|p\b\|_F^2 \\
 &= \L\| \pmatrix{H \\ {\l} I}p\;-\;\pmatrix{b\\0} \R\|_F^2 \\
 &= \L\| \H p - \q \R\|_F^2 \\
}$$
Thus the problem becomes
$$\eqalign{
&\min_{p}&\L\| \H p - \q \R\|_F^2 \\
&{\rm s.t.}\;\;&p\ge0 \\
}$$
which is known as the Non-Negative Least Squares (NNLS) problem.

Many solvers exist for this, e.g. Matlab's `lsqnonneg` or SciPy's `scipy.optimize.nnls`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not. The condition you wrote, I assume, is that the gradient of the Lagrangian is zero. You forgot the condition that $P$ is non-negative.

Moreover, when you have inequality constraints, the optimality conditions also include complementarity, namely, $P \odot \Lambda= 0$, which is clearly nonlinear. So LP will not help you here.